# How to generate domain from an enum while generating DDL from data model?

Tags: java, enums, jpa-2.1, hibernate-5.x, sql-domain

Is there a way to generate a domain for a field that is defined as `enum` while generating DDL from the data model?

The default behaviour for fields that are defined as `enum` is either `EnumType.STRING` or `EnumType.ORDINAL`. In this particular case I use `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`.

### MyEnum.java

```
public enum MyEnum {
   MY_VALUE_1, MY_VALUE_2, MY_VALUE_3
}
```

### MyEntity.java

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
public class MyEntity {
   @javax.persistence.Id
   private long id;

   @javax.persistence.Enumerated(javax.persistence.EnumType.STRING)
   private MyEnum status;
}
```

This is unfortunately defined as "only" `character varying(255)` (I am using PostgreSQL RDBMS).

```
ALTER TABLE myentity ADD COLUMN status character varying(255);
```

This of course gives an opportunity to put garbage there that has nothing to do with the actual `enum`.

```
INSERT INTO myentity(id, status) VALUES (1, 'THIS_HAS_NOTHING_TO_DO_WITH_THE_ENUM');
```

In this place I would like to be able to give a hint to Hibernate to generate a domain with only those values allowed that actually belong to the enumeration.

As a workaround I wanted to generate a check constraint using `@Check` annotation. This however regrettably cannot be done dynamically. I wanted to loop through the `MyEnum.values()` in order to generate this check so that I do not have to change it at the same time when the enum gets additional values.

```
public class MyEntity {
   @javax.persistence.Id
   private long id;

   @javax.persistence.Enumerated(javax.persistence.EnumType.STRING)
   @org.hibernate.annotations.Check(constraints = String.format("currentclub in %s", PlayerStatus.values()))
   private MyEnum status;
}
```

This of course leads to a syntax error

> The value for annotation attribute Check.constraints must be a constant expression.

which is clear to me as the attribute value must be determined at compilation time.

Is there any other way to do it in a clever way?